# How do you loop through and display MYSQL query results that GROUP BY date?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `pools` that has a `poolid` and a `createddate` for every entry. I'm making a sort of dashboard for myself where I want to see a listing of the # of pools created each day for the past week (including "so far today").

I have this far, but this spits back simply "8", which actually is the number of pools created so far today, but how do I retrieve the number of pools for yesterday, 2 days ago, 3 days ago, etc?

```
    $today= date('Y-m-d');
    $weekago=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*), poolid FROM pools WHERE `createddate` BETWEEN :weekago AND :today GROUP BY createddate ORDER BY createddate DESC");  
        $stmt->execute([':weekago' => $weekago, ':today' => $today]);
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
            $numpoolssofartoday= $stmt->rowCount();
        }

echo $numpoolssofartoday;
```

Tweaked and got the following to do what I want:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as numpools, createddate FROM pools WHERE `createddate` BETWEEN :weekago AND :today GROUP BY createddate ORDER BY createddate DESC");  
$stmt->execute([':weekago' => $weekago, ':today' => $today]);
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $numpoolspastweek .= date('m-d',strtotime($row['createddate'])) . " " . $row['numpools']. "<br>";
}
```

That outputs:

```
12-02 11
12-01 24
11-30 16
11-29 17
11-28 22
11-27 22
11-26 16
11-25 17
```

Comment: The same way you loop though those that don't group....  What dates to you have in there

Comment: DB related questions are always easier if you can set up a fiddle with some example data in it.  such as on this site and then post the url https://www.db-fiddle.com/  you can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` to output your tables schema, then you just need a bit of data in it using `INSERT INTO`  What you have should work, or be really close unless all your dates are the same, then you get only one from the aggravate function, the `poolid` is problematic though using this.

Comment: Also you should use a `while` loop like `while(false !== ( $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))` kudos on using PDO and prepared statements

Comment: Thanks, it was an existing site using mysqli and it was a b**** to convert all of them to PDO, but it had to be done based on everything I read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are over writing your output:

```
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $numpoolssofartoday= $stmt->rowCount();
}
echo $numpoolssofartoday;
```

Do you see it now? the `$numpoolssofartoday` should be an array of counts.  Or at the least you should output from within the loop depending what you are trying to do. ( test for example ).

Also your using `rowCount` which count's all the return rows for the query. Instead of using the count returned by the query.

So I would change your SQL to make it easier to get the total, and add the date, the poolid is irrelevant, as it will not be correct because you are combining multiple rows with the `GROUP BY` clause so

```
$sql = 'SELECT createddate, COUNT(poolid) AS total FROM ...';

// I'm to lazy for that looping, and been coding to much so I like to type as little as possible.

$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

Also I would use `Fetch Group` with the first column being the data you grouped by so you get an array like this, and can skip the loop.

```
[
    '2017-12-3' => ['total' => '3'],
    '2017-12-2' => ['total' => '5']
]
```

Comment: So I tweaked it more and got it working but it's a little different than what you wrote.  You don't have to (you've already been very helpful), but I'm going to add what I got working to my question and if you have any thoughts on why it might not be the best way to do it, please share.

Comment: I just did a better solution, updated it. to use `FETCH_GROUP`  If I remember right it works on the first returned field, so date would need to be first.